# Using Jest with ReactDOM.findDOMNode

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

Jest (technically, Jest snapshot testing with ReactTestRenderer) [does not work with ReactDOM.findDOMNode](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7371).

I've seen where I can work around this using Jest mocks. For example, if my `ChannelScanner` component uses my `RadioButtonSet` component, which wraps [react-widgets' SelectList](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/selectlist), then putting the following code in `ChannelScanner.test.js` allows snapshot testing to work:

```
jest.mock('../../src/components/forms/RadioButtonSet', () => 'RadioButtonSet');
```

**However**, this seems to break encapsulation: RadioButtonSet's tests have to set up mocks based on the components it uses, and the transitive components that *they* use, and this work has to be repeated for every component.

What's the best way to handle this? Short of enabling [automock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#automock-boolean), is there a good way to say, "This module knows that it needs to mock itself whenever it appears?"